# Generate & Publish (ClickOnce) from script inside Visual Studio

Tags: c#, automation, clickonce

I have nine applications within the same Visual Studio solution. All get deployed via ClickOnce (to different locations within the same host), and currently I need to right click and do all the publish wizard. But I'm thinking if there's an automated way to do this using an script (ideally one where I can just write the host password (for the FTP)).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. We use MSBuild to publish via ClickOnce and upload via FTP.

Google MSBuild Tasks and MS Community Build Task

This is an untested extract of our build script and should get you started:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <!-- Documentation:

    http://msbuildhg.codeplex.com/documentation
    http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/

    -->
    <PropertyGroup>

        <MSBuildMercurialPath>.</MSBuildMercurialPath>
        <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>.</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>

        <BuildInputDir>src</BuildInputDir>
        <BuildOutputDir>build</BuildOutputDir>
        <TestOutputDir>test</TestOutputDir>
        <PublishOutputDir>publish</PublishOutputDir>
        <PublishDir>..\..\$(PublishOutputDir)</PublishDir>
        <SolutionToCompile>$(BuildInputDir)\EventLogger.sln</SolutionToCompile>

        <!-- Settings -->
        <Company>Veodin</Company>
        <Product>KeyRocket</Product>

        <!-- ClickOnce deployment -->
        <InstallUrl>http://download.veodin.com/keyrocket/</InstallUrl>
        <UpdateUrl>http://download.veodin.com/update/keyrocket/</UpdateUrl>

        <!-- Upload_FTP -->
        <UploadMethod>FTP</UploadMethod>
        <ftpHost>ftp.com</ftpHost>                                                      <!-- e.g. 'mroc.de' !!! -->
        <ftpUser>user</ftpUser>
        <ftpPass>password</ftpPass>
        <ServerDir>/download/</ServerDir>  <!-- E.g. 'downloads/test/' !!! -->
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Import Project="Tools\MSBuild.Mercurial.Tasks" />
    <Import Project="Tools\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />

    <Target Name="Clean">
        <Message Text="-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"/>
        <RemoveDir Directories="$(BuildOutputDir)" />
        <RemoveDir Directories="$(TestOutputDir)" />
        <RemoveDir Directories="$(PublishOutputDir)" />
    </Target>


    <Target Name="Publish">
        <Message Text="-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"/>
        <Message Text="Publishing version $(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision), Company=$(Company), Product=$(Product)"/>
        <PropertyGroup>
            <PublishArgs>Configuration=Automated_Build;PublishDir=$(PublishDir)\;InstallUrl=$(InstallUrl);UpdateUrl=$(UpdateUrl);ApplicationVersion=$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision);ApplicationRevision=$(Revision);IsWebBootstrapper=true;BootstrapperEnabled=true;PublisherName=$(Company);ProductName=$(Product)</PublishArgs>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <MSBuild
            Projects="$(BuildInputDir)\VeodinKeyRocket\VeodinKeyRocket.csproj"
            Targets="Clean"
            Properties="$(PublishArgs)" />
        <MSBuild
            Projects="$(BuildInputDir)\VeodinKeyRocket\VeodinKeyRocket.csproj"
            Targets="Rebuild"
            Properties="$(PublishArgs)" />
        <MSBuild
            Projects="$(BuildInputDir)\VeodinKeyRocket\VeodinKeyRocket.csproj"
            Targets="Publish"
            Properties="$(PublishArgs)" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Upload_FTP" Condition=" '$(UploadMethod)' == 'FTP'">
        <Message Text="-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"/>
        <Message Text="Uploading to $(ftpHost)/$(ServerDir)" />
        <FtpUploadDirectoryContent
            ServerHost="$(ftpHost)"
            Port="21"
            Username="$(ftpUser)"
            Password="$(ftpPass)"
            LocalDirectory="$(PublishOutputDir)"
            RemoteDirectory="$(ServerDir)"
            Recursive="true" />
    </Target>


    <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="Clean;Publish;Upload_FTP;">
        <Message Text="Clean;Publish;Upload_FTP;"/>
    </Target>

</Project>
```